# Image does not load in .load with jquery (broken link)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good night people.

I'm using this script to get data from a page, with the correct proxy:

```
 $(function(){
var proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
var url = "https://www.resultadofacil.com.br/resultado-do-jogo-do-bicho/BA";
var urlscript = btoa(url);
var urldescript = atob(urlscript);
$('.tab1').load(proxyurl + urldescript + "  .col-lg-4");  
});
```

This is the error: https://prnt.sc/vl5olb

In advance, thank you. I'm using jQuery, but it can be pure javascript too.

Comment: I can't see those images in [this](https://www.resultadofacil.com.br/resultado-do-jogo-do-bicho/BA) page. Are you sure the images belong to this page?

Comment: Yeah. Run the script in any local div, you will see that it does not execute

Comment: Can't reproduce - https://jsbin.com/hemirik/edit?html,js,output